# como pasar query sql a ORM Eloquent de laravel?

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent, orm

tengo una query hecha en sql y la quisiera pasar al ORM de Laravel que es eloquent y estoy teniendo bastante complicaciones. La query sirve para obtener la farmacia mas cerca de la latitud y longitud que uno desea. Esta es mi query en sql:

```
SELECT id
    ,latitude
    ,longitude
    ,name
    ,(6371 
        * ACOS( SIN(RADIANS(latitude)) 
                * SIN(RADIANS(4.6665578)) + COS(RADIANS(longitude - - 74.0524521)) 
                * COS(RADIANS(latitude)) 
                * COS(RADIANS(4.6665578))
               )
     ) AS distance
FROM pharmacies /* 1 KM a la redonda */
ORDER BY distance ASC LIMIT 1;
```

les agradeceria mucho su ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Usa DB::raw para todo lo que sea query sql

```
$data= DB::table('users')
    ->select(DB::raw('id,latitude,longitude,name,
      (6371 * ACOS( SIN(RADIANS(latitude)) 
      * SIN(RADIANS(4.6665578)) + COS(RADIANS(longitude - - 74.0524521)) 
      * COS(RADIANS(latitude)) 
      * COS(RADIANS(4.6665578))
      )) AS distance'))
    ->orderByRaw('distance ASC')
    ->limit(1)
    ->get();
```

[Documentación Oficial](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#raw-expressions)

Comment: Se te agradece el apoyo, sin embargo en estos casos se nos recomienda evitar responder la publicación ya que la persona autora de la misma no ha agregado ningún intento al respecto, lo cual hace que su pregunta no se ajuste a [ask]  y eventualmente termine cerrada